# How can I add attachments to a post with WP-API

Tags: wp-api

I am creating posts with [WP-API](http://wp-api.org/#posts_create-a-post) and I want to attach files to them.

I see a section in the docs saying ["create an attachment"](http://wp-api.org/#media_create-an-attachment), but it seems that it doesn't associate the file with a post.

I also don't see any other obvious way to associate a media/attachment with a post.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you find how to attach a media to a post ? I can't seem to find how

Comment: @punkbit Hi. Finally, I simply added a link to the attachment in the post body. I doubt if WP supports directly attaching files to posts.

Comment: I've done the same thing : ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that WordPress (or WP-API) does not link media to posts, but you have to add a link on your post to the media/attachment.